# Neo4j Movie Tutorial query

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am looking at the Neo4j movie sample project:
https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j-4

One of the examples recommends new co-actors for Tom Hanks i.e.
Find actors that Tom Hanks hasn't yet worked with, but his co-actors have.

The Query:

```
MATCH (tom:Person {name:"Tom Hanks"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActors),
      (coActors)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m2)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(cocoActors)
WHERE NOT (tom)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m2)
RETURN cocoActors.name AS Recommended, count(*) AS Strength ORDER BY Strength DESC
```

The top 3 results are:
Recommended Strength
Tom Cruise  5
Zach Grenier    5
Helen Hunt  4

However Helen Hunt is returned in the list of Tom Hanks co-actors:

```
MATCH (tom:Person {name:"Tom Hanks"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActors) RETURN coActors.name
```

AND Tom Hanks is returned in the list of Helen Hunt co-actors:

```
MATCH (tom:Person {name:"Helen Hunt"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActors) RETURN coActors.name
```

Is this a bug in Neo4j or in the query given in the tutorial? 
If it is a bug in the query What is the correct query?

Comment: Where do you see this query? I can't seem to find it in the movies-java-spring-data-neo4j-4 repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That query isn't finding people who Tom Hanks hasn't worked with yet. I'm not sure what they were going for there, but to accomplish that you should do:

```
MATCH (tom:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActors:Person),
      (coActors)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coCoActors:Person)
WHERE tom.name = 'Tom Hanks' AND
      NOT (tom)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coCoActors)
RETURN coCoActors.name AS recommended, count(*) AS strength 
ORDER BY strength DESC;
```

The line `WHERE NOT (tom)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m2)` from their query doesn't really make any sense; all that's doing is asserting that Tom Hanks didn't act in any of the movies that his co-actors and co-co-actors acted in together. It does nothing to assert that Tom Hanks has never acted with the people bound to `coCoActors`.

Comment: Funny enough in [guide to a simple recommendation engine](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-build-a-recommendation-engine/) they have the correct form of the query, stating "Also you’d probably want to state that Tom Hanks never worked with the recommended people, not just not in movies that his co-actors worked in." You could also add a restriction `AND id(tom)<>id(coCoActos)` to avoid cases where coCoActors matches to tom.